# Historical mean for a dataset that increases in size

Tags: r

I am asked to get historical mean of a dataset as its forecasts. I am supposed to get forecast for time, t= 1175 to t=1675.
For t=1175, the forecast should be the mean from t=1 to t=1174. 
For t=1176, the forecast should be the mean from t=1 to t=1175. And so on ..

ret_xrp is a dataset that contains a series of returns from time t=1 to t=1675.

```
fc_xrp_mean <- list()
fit_xrp_mean <- list()

for (i in 1:500){
  fit_xrp_mean[[i]]<- mean(ret_xrp[(1):(1174+i)])
 fc_xrp_mean[[i]] <- predict(fit_xrp_mean[[i]], n.ahead = 1)
 print(fc_xrp_mean)
}
```

After running the above codes, I get a list of NAs. Really need help. Thanks :D

Comment: Could you attach some example data? Use `dput()` or `head()` on your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

In case your dataset is ordered by `t`, you can extend the following base-R loop for your needs:

```
# sample data
x <- data.frame(t=1:2000,value=2000:1)

# iterating over all rows
for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  x$mean[i] <- mean(x$value[1:i],na.rm=T)
}
```

Ideally convert your data to lists and do additional operations after the loop to not slow R down too much.